# Create vector of dates by start date and end date

Tags: matlab, datetime, vector

Is it possible to create a vector automatically or progressively with dates. I want to ask the user about the starting date and the final date and I'd to fill a vector with the dates and the ones between both.

so abstractly:

"what is the first date?" '...' firstDate = '...'  --> "what is the final date?" '...' finalDate='...'

and following, I'd like to fill in a vector all of the dates between firstDate and finalDate. is this possible in Matlab, and how? Is there a function to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `linspace` after the user input:

```
%// prompt and user input
prompt1 = 'What is the first date? (yyyy-MM-dd)\n';
prompt2 = 'What is the last date? (yyyy-MM-dd)\n';

startDate = datenum(input(prompt1,'s'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
endDate = datenum(input(prompt2,'s'),'yyyy-mm-dd')

% number of days
numdays = endDate-startDate

% array of dates
alldays = linspace(startDate,endDate,numdays)
DateString = datestr(alldays, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

---

For the input **1989-07-01** and **1989-07-07** it will return:

```
DateString =

07/01/1989
07/02/1989
07/03/1989
07/04/1989
07/05/1989
07/07/1989
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates can be called using `datevec`, `datestr`, `datenum` etc. `datenum` will be your best bet, since you can then create your vector using

```
DateVector = datenum(firstDate):datenum(finalDate);
```

This will create a vector containing dates per day. The way back is to say `datestr(DateVector)`

Comment: thanks a lot. do you also know, how i can increase time, especially hours? if i want to get all 24 hours of a day. a vector, containing: '01-01-2015 00:00',  '01-01-2015 01:00', ... , '01-01-2015 23:00'

Comment: create a datevec, instead of a datenum. datevec is a vector structured as [year month day hour minute second] in integers (still class double). Then simply keep everything but hour the same and use hour=0:23;